# Import content to AEM

Tags: import, aem, crx

We have a lot content that need to be imported in AEM.
what is best way to import it? Is that any possibilities to import from excel file?

[check this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3l4l.jpg)

An good example for exporting is here /etc/importers/bulkeditor.html we can export the file with single "Properties / Columns" where i can define the Root Path and Properties.

I tried this packet but dos not contain what I like. https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-custom-excel-service-experience.html

Comment: Where does the content come from? Another AEM/CQ instance? Or some 3rd party stuff..?

Comment: Is the same platform actually i need to add just in properties for a page.

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:4502/etc/importers/bulkeditor.html

[documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/administering/bulk_editor.html)

I just made a test following the instructions on the link above and it worked.

My test:

Root path = /content/myapp-path/rootpage

Query parameters = "jcr:title": Title of pages that I what to include in the search

Content mode = unchecked

Properties / Columnos = 
sling:resourceType and 
jcr:title

Custom properties / Columns =
landingTags

Clicked Search... and worked.

Comment: Thanx for answering.
Yes this works fine also for me! But I'm checking something oposit to do.
so i have file and need to upload it and to fill the property! for this I'm looking.
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Importing data to AEM can be done in lots of ways.

What is the "right" way for you, depends on your specific requirements.

- Is this a one time import, or are you rather planning to write a
  reusable import tool?
- Is the import done by programmers or admins, or
  rather by editors?
- Do you need fault tolerance or a rollback? Are you
  working on productive instances?
- ...

Here are a few of the more or less common ways (ordered from cheap/fast to extensive/comfortable) along with links to the documentation or examples:

1. Write a bash-script and post values with cURL requests (1)
2. Upload data in DAM, write EventHandler (2), (7) or a workflow (3) with a workflow launcher (4) and parse the data, afterwards change the repository.
3. Upload data in separate file in an own component with a file upload section (5), parse the data and change the repository.

For parsing excel data I would suggest you use apache poi (6), which is already included in AEM. But using formats like csv, json or xml will maybe save you lots of parsing efforts.

(1): http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/adobe-cq5-aem-curl-commands/

(2): https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/index.html?org/osgi/service/event/EventHandler.html

(3): https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/extending/workflows/wf-extending.html

(4): https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/operations/workflows/wf-start.html

(5): https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/uploading-files-aem1.html

(6): https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

(7): code example

```
@Service
@Component(immediate = true, policy = ConfigurationPolicy.OPTIONAL, description = "Listen to page modification events and track them.")
@Properties(value = { @Property(name = "event.topics", value = { PageEvent.EVENT_TOPIC, DamEvent.EVENT_TOPIC}, propertyPrivate = true),
                      @Property(name = JobConsumer.PROPERTY_TOPICS, value = ModificationEventHandler.JOB_TOPICS, propertyPrivate = true) })
public class ModificationEventHandler implements EventHandler, JobConsumer {
@Override public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    logger.trace("Checking event.");
    PageEvent pageEvent = PageEvent.fromEvent(event);
    DamEvent damEvent = DamEvent.fromEvent(event);
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    if (damEvent != null) {
        // DamEvent is not serializable, so we cannot add the complete event to the map.
        logger.trace("Event on {} is a dam event ({}).", damEvent.getAssetPath(), damEvent.getType().name());
        properties.put(DAM_EVENT_ASSET_PATH, damEvent.getAssetPath());
    }
    if (pageEvent != null) {
        logger.trace("Event is a page event.");
        properties.put(PAGE_EVENT, pageEvent);
    }
    logger.trace("Adding new job.");
    jobManager.addJob(JOB_TOPICS, properties);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I need to grab rss feeds periodically and creating content page regarding each feed entry with custom fields, any idea for that?

Answer (score 0):

Content can be imported via the SlingPostServlet with `:operation=import`: https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#importing-content-structures. Here is an example adapted from the page:

```bash
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:4502/content/mysite/mypage \ 
    -F":operation=import" \
    -F":contentType=json" 
    -F":name=sample" \    
    -F":content={ 'jcr:primaryType': 'nt:unstructured', 'propOne' : 'propOneValue', 'childOne' : { 'childPropOne' : true } }"
```

Another author-friendly option is the [CSV Asset Importer](http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/csv-asset-importer.html) included with the [ACS AEM Tools](http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/) package. You can save an Excel file to CSV so this should be the easy option.